# What's the total reputation on site X?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Just wondering, is there any place where I can find the total reputation of all users on XYZ site combined?

Comment: What meaning are you assigning to this number?

Comment: No meaning whatsoever, Sir.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here it is: (from data.stackexchange.com)

[What is the total reputation of site X](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/186673/what-is-the-total-reputation-of-site-x)

If you want to exclude users having only 1 reputation, you can pass `y` in the `exclude` parameter. By default it's value is `n`.

You can switch the site using site switcher available under the <kbd>Run Query</kbd> button.

Comment: So, excluding ones: 177274663, or ~180 million. Which means Jon Skeet has less than 0.3% of the total: clearly work to do :-).

Comment: Both of you made my life better, for which I'm eternally grateful.

Comment: @Sherlock - Since the reputation will be changed time by time I didn't include it in my answer. You may add it as a comment.